# What does Irr($\alpha,F$) means?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I was reading some abstract algebra thing about splitting fields and I saw this notatios, I don´t know what it means, can somebody help?

Comment: The minimal monic polynomian $p(x)\in F[x]$ with a root $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over F, it's defined as follows (assuming that $\alpha$ is in some field extension of F:

put $I = \{f\in F[x] | f(\alpha) = 0\} $ this is an ideal.

$Irr(\alpha,F)$ is then the unique monic polynomial generating I (or alternatively the unique monic in I which is irreducible)

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much!